# Flow-typed libdefs outdated for `react-router-native`?

Tags: react-router, flowtype, flow-typed, react-router-native

Are flow-typed libdefs outdated for `react-router-native`?

When `flow`ing this working code, I get:

```
3: import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-native';
            ^^^^^ Named import from module `react-router-native`. This module has no named export called `
```

Checked out the libdef in flow-typed (https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-router-native_v4.x.x/flow_v0.53-/react-router-native_v4.x.x.js) and it doesn't seem to export any of these types.

I'm new to Flow and flow-typed so I may be doing something wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libdefs for `react-router-native v4.x.x` are indeed outdated and should be updated.

I reported an issue ([`flowtype/flow-typed#1309`](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/issues/1309)) and will try to send in a PR tonight.